# Changes in rainfalls, sea level and tropical cyclones

Tags: sea-level, tropical-cyclone, rainfall, reference-request

Is there any scientific evidence that exploitation of natural resources (fossil energies, forests etc.) affects rainfalls or sea level, which can represent extreme events?

I read IPCC 2014 report and I see some claims like not all climate scientists agree on a variable catastrophic event probability.

They wrote the following sentences :

> In the future, it is likely that the frequency of tropical cyclones
>   globally will either decrease or remain unchanged, but there will be a
>   likely increase in global mean tropical cyclone precipitation rates
>   and maximum wind speed.

Is there any scientific references that justify this kind of claim ?

Comment: How about referencing where in the report the quote comes from ... and IPCC is FULL of references.

Comment: IPCC reports are not referencing always to scientific papers. Especially, they have just wrote this sentence and not other additional information about the issue

Comment: Not true... if you give the location of the reference, it would help get your question answered.  Perhaps you are reading the summary report which links to the larger documents.